# How to use Filename, modify date and publish date as a quick part in word app

Tags: quick-parts

we want to insert filename, modify date and publish date in a word document template as quick part connected to sharepoint. These values should populate from sharepoint. For example when document name is changed, we should see new document name inside. We use office 365 solution.

May you help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think for this you should create a custom document template in SharePoint document library, in order to that follow the below steps:

1. Navigate to the site where you want to create your library.
2. Select Settings Gear shaped settings button , and then select Add an
   App.
3. Select Document Library.
4. Select Advanced Options.
5. Add a name, optional description, versioning, and if applicable,
   whether you want the library to receive email.
6. Select the default application file format and version from the
   Document Template dropdown.
7. Click Create.

**Customize the default template for a document library**

To customize the default template, follow these steps. There are two ways you can change the default template:

1. If your document or form library has a default file template for a
   program compatible with SharePoint, then you can edit the default
   template.
2. For other programs, you cannot directly edit the default template,
   but you can copy a new template file to the Forms folder of the
   library to specify a custom template.

**Edit the default file template**

3. Navigate to the site where your library is located.
4. In SharePoint Server, on the ribbon, select the Library tab, then select Library Settings.
5. For SharePoint Online, select Settings Gear shaped settings button ,
   and then select Library settings.
6. Under General Settings, select Advanced settings.
7. In the Document Template section, under the Template URL field,
   select Edit Template. One of the following happens:
8. If your site is a part of an Office 365 subscription, at this point,
   you may be prompted to enter your Office 365 subscription username and password.
9. Document library    The template opens in an app that is compatible
   with SharePoint and that is associated with the file type of the
   current template. For example, Word opens if the default template is
   a Word template, or Excel opens if the default template is an Excel
   worksheet.
10. Form library    The template opens either in a program compatible
    with SharePoint, either an XML-based form design program, such as
    InfoPath, or an XML editor.
11. Make the changes that you want, and then save the template. For
     SharePoint Online, save the template with a new filename. Close the program if you no longer need it open, or switch to your site.
12. Depending on your form design program, you may need to republish
     the template to the library on your site from your program.
13. In your site, at the bottom of the Document or Form Library
     Advanced Settings page, and select OK.

For details refer to the below MSDN article:

[Set a custom template for a SharePoint library](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/set-a-custom-template-for-a-sharepoint-library-8e0177eb-46bd-4346-9998-330c32733c25?ui=en-us&rs=en-gb&ad=gb)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. But i want to use sharepoint's document publish date, modification date and document name in the word document. But i cannot see them as a quick part.